# Proper inputType for Credit Cards

Tags: android

I'm trying to devise an input type for a field which will accept credit card numbers.

I had been using inputType="number" - but that won't let people with hardware keyboards hit the space bar.. when they do it jumps to another field in the activity.

I'd like to allow users to use a space in their numbers if they want, or, at least, make it so that if users with a hardware keyboard hit the space when I'm only allowing numbers it won't leave the credit card number EditText.

Ideally I'd be able to implement some interface and have my own custom inputType, but I'm not sure that's possible.

- Is it possible to allow numbers and spaces, while showing the numbers soft keyboard?

Comment: I've tried leaving it "number" and adding             android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction" to the EditText, but still - when the hardware keyboard space bar is hit, it jumps to a seemingly random EditText further down the activity layout.

Comment: ["To intercept hard keys, override InputMethodService.onKeyDown()"](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html). Read from bottom heading "Intercepting hard key events". Might help?

Comment: If you can't find a way to intercept try using a normal TextView and manually open the number keyboard. [These resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=input) were really helpful to me when I was working on InputMethods.

Comment: When it's a soft keyboard, then it works perfectly. The thing is, if the phone has a hardware keyboard then I want to allow the user to use it without forcing them to have a soft keyboard on the screen as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer for you but here are some resources I picked up:

I found this clue to "catch" hard key presses: "[To intercept hard keys, override InputMethodService.onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html)". Read from bottom heading "Intercepting hard key events".

If you can't find a way to intercept and deal with the "space" key, I would suggest using a normal TextView and manually opening the number keyboard rather than the qwerty one (Go here for more info on general [Input Reference](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=input)). You can then validate key pressed from the hard keyboard.

Sorry I couldn't give you a more solid answer!

Comment: I think this is what I'll have to do in this case.. but it's strange because only the spacebar will jump the cursor to another field - any other non-allowed character just does nothing and leaves the "number" field selected.

Answer (score 8):

The best choise is [InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME)

Comment: What works for me is add this `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME` and then adding character filter manually

Answer (score 4):

How about `android:inputType="phone"` in your layout xml file?

Comment: I am also interested in insights regarding this, this looks much better showing up keyboard with bigger numbers